# Is it possible to override a base method with a more specific (by return type) method?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, class-design

I have classes like this.

```
public class Base{
    public virtual Base Clone(){ ...... }
}

public class Derived:Base{
    public Derived Clone(){ ...... }
    private override Base Clone(){ return Clone(); }

}
```

This code, of course, gives me some compile errors, one saying there are two Clone() methods in Derived class and the other saying that overriding method must be in the same accessibility level as the overridden one.
Now, since the Derived.Clone() method which overrides Base.Clone() is never needed directly, I'd like to hide it with the more specific Derived.Clone() method which returns a Derived object. I know this can be done in C# with interfaces, but is it possible to do the same with classes?

Comment: It it not possible as the two methods of `Derived` would differ only by return type. Why would the first one be needed?

Comment: Why can't you put code from Derived.Clone directly into the override?

Comment: It would be nice but unfortunately it's not - you have to use generics as @MelnikovI suggests

Comment: No, it's not possible, trying using generic return type.

Comment: @Codor,amnezjak 
I'd like to return the Derived type to avoid cast, since Clone() only returns a Derived object anyways.

Comment: More or less same solutions posted for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911008/avoid-explicit-type-casting-when-overriding-inherited-methods/23911451#23911451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the way you show. A common approach is to introduce an extra method for the implementation:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base Clone() { return CloneImpl(); }
    protected virtual Base CloneImpl() { ... }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public new Derived Clone() { ... }
    protected override Base CloneImpl() { return Clone(); }
}
```

This then satisfies all expectations of polymorphism, substitution, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To go a little further on the answer of Marc which is in basis what you need, I would change the signature of the internal method:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base Clone()
    {
        Base b = new Base();
        CloneImpl(b);
        return b;
    }
    protected virtual void CloneImpl(Base b) { ... }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public new Derived Clone()
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        this.CloneImpl(d);
        return d;
    }
    protected override void CloneImpl(Base b)
    {
        Derived d = b as Derived;
        ...
        base.CloneImpl(d);
    }
}
```

In this way the internal method can do the work for the type itself and let the base class do the part they have in common.